# WebStorm IDE won't use built-In server

Tags: webstorm

When I open an html file in WebStorm 9, then hover in the right hand corner to launch the built-in browser (like I've done a million times), Chrome loads the url (`http://localhost:63342/project/file.html`) and throws a "This webpage is not available".

- I've reinstalled WebStorm.
- I've tried modifying my `etc/hosts`, but found it was empty, which was weird.
- I checked the port to see if anything else was using it, finding nothing weird.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So... try the following, stop when it starts working  1) Restart Webstorm 2) Kill all instances of webstorm 3) restart computer....
Other than that, the only weird thing is the empty /etc/hosts file, add `127.0.0.1 localhost` and see if that works

Comment: Which step solved your problem?

Comment: Adding the 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file was all that was needed. Thanks again.